# TypeScript catches type error in webpack, but not in vs code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have project A and B that have installed exact same dependencies: `typescript:4.2.4`, `ts-loader: 9.0.2`. Project A compiles through webpack fine with no type errors showing on both vs code and during compilation. But Project B on other hand shows no error on vs code, but webpack catches type error during compilation. Why could cause a difference? Only difference I found is Project B uses workspace typescript version of `4.5.5`, while Project A uses `4.6.4`. tsconfigjson file for both are identical so I'm not sure what's causing the difference in type checking. Also, inside of `node_modules/ts-loader`, Project A is using typescript `4.6.2`, but Project B is using typescript `4.3.2`. Not sure how there could be a difference as in package.json both ts-loader is using 9.0.2. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Without more info it's hard to tell but first thing to try is to change the version of Typescript to match. If it's not possible, look up the changes that happened between `4.5.5` and `4.6.4`: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/. By glancing at it I can see keywords such as "breaking changes", "control flow analysis", or "Indexed Access Inference". Any of these can change the behaviour of your types

Comment: What's the difference between VS Code TypeScript version and Workspace version? I have selected Use VS Code version for both projects which is 4.9.5. Is Workspace TypeScript version being used somewhere?

Comment: Workspace version is the version of Typescript installed in node_modules. If you want consistent behaviour you should use this option and make sure any additional tooling matches. I'm not sure what you mean about project B using `4.3.2` via ts-loader. A possible explanation if this setting takes precedence for some reason is that you use features absent from this version.

Comment: Solved it by npm installing typescript version 4.9.5 on Project B.